# How to combine SKCanvasView with other views in the same page?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to show a `SKCanvasView` and other views like `ListView` or `Label`s on the same Page of a `Xamarin Form` project for `Android`.

My Xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="AndroidExample.Principal"
             Title="myApp">

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
      <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvas" PaintSurface="Canvas_Paint_Surface"/>
      <Label Text="EXAMPLE" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

It does not show anything when I deploy the App. `Label`and `SKCanvasView`are hidden or something like that.

I have also tried without using `StackLayout`, with same results :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a grid instead

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
                 x:Class="AndroidExample.Principal"
                 Title="myApp">

      <Grid>
          <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvas" PaintSurface="Canvas_Paint_Surface"/>
          <Label Text="EXAMPLE" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>   
     </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

With this, your SKCanvasView will fill the entire view and you can place any controls above. A StackLayout stacks items. With your current code, SKCanvasView has Height =0;